# Using the --globals variable with MochaJS testing suite

Tags: javascript, testing, sails.js, mocha.js

I am trying to do a variant of end-to-end testing on a [sailjs](http://sailsjs.org) system using [mocha](http://mochajs.org/). What I want to do is to simulate the action program flow by doing things like creating a user, and then performing other action with that user.

I'd like to be able to separate my tests into separate files that run in order in relation to different operations, such as "register new user" etc. To do this I need to be able to pass values between testing files.

Mocha contains an option setting `--globals <value1, value2, etc>`. Here is the description from the docs:

> --globals                allow the given comma-delimited global [names]

However, I've been unable to get this to work. Here's what I've tried. I have a bootstrap.test.js file that does basic before and after operations, starting and stopping sails:

```
var Sails = require('sails'),
  sails;

before(function(done) {
  Sails.lift({
    log: {
        level: 'error'
    }
  }, function(err, server) {
    sails = server;
    if (err) return done(err);
    // here you can load fixtures, etc.
    done(err, sails);
  });
});

after(function(done) {
  // here you can clear fixtures, etc.
  sails.lower(done);
});
```

Then let's say I have two test files `a.js` and `b.js` that will run consecutively and for testing purposes contain very little:

a.js:

```
var user = 'some user';
```

b.js:

```
console.log( user );
```

If I then run `mocha --globals`, I get the error:

> ReferenceError: user is not defined

What am I doing wrong here? I have been unable to find anywhere on the web a description of how this would be used.

Comment: Seems I was able to get this working by just using global.[variable] and once assigned a value can be accessed in other tests. Does this help?

Comment: Can you please give a more extensive code example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood the purpose of `--globals`. It *may* be used when you use `--check-leaks`. The `--check-leaks` option checks whether the tests are leaking variables into the global space. Consider this suite:

```
it("one", function () {
    foo = 1;
});
```

If you run it with `mocha --check-leaks` you'll get an error because the test creates a new `foo` global. You can prevent the error with `mocha --check-leaks --globals foo`. In large projects there are perhaps leaks that are deemed to be okay and so using the `--globals` option allows turning off errors for those cases that are okay.

Now, how can you achieve what you wanted to do? You cannot create a global variable if you use `var`. Your `a.js` would have to be:

```
user = 'some user';
```

Moreover, by default Mocha does not guarantee an order when it loads test files. You *could* use `--sort` to guarantee that `a.js` is loaded first but you are then forced to use a name that will guarantee this order. I prefer to use `--require a` which tells Mocha to require module `a` before it starts reading the test files. Your module could be called `z` and would still be loaded before any test file. At any rate, by removing `var` and using `--require` your test files will see your global. (I tried it: it works.)

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me using sailsjs (I think there would be a better way to do this), one of the first test that I run is to register a user:

```
describe('#Should register test user', function () {
    it('should register user', function (done) {
        request(sails.hooks.http.app)
            .post('/auth/registertest')
            .send({
                "email": "email@foo.com.au",
                "password": "foo",
                "firstname": "foo",
                "lastname": "foo",
                "location": {
                    "name": "foo",
                    "id": "54d733795ed3f5140b0a761b"
                }
            })
            .expect(200).end(function (err, res) {
                if (err) return done(err);
                global.email = "email@tpg.com.au";
                global.token = res.body.token;
                done();
            })
    });
});
```

Then I am able to access the global email and token variables in other test files that run after the register user test, for example the below calls my api and uses the global token variable in the Authorization header.

```
describe('#auth access to users bunches', function () {
    it('should get 200', function (done) {
        request(sails.hooks.http.app)
            .get('/bunch/byuser')
            .set('Authorization', 'bearer ' + token)
            .expect(200).end(function (err, res) {
                if (err) return done(err);
                done();
            })
    });
});
```